# Vue: Reacting to a nested list object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an an array of objects called `links`.  It is shaped like this:

```
links = [
   {'title': "foo", 'url': "http://www.com"},
   {'title': "foo1", 'url': "http://www2.com"},
]
```

I am using a `v-for` to populate this data in a list.

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in links">
    <input :value="item.url" />
</div>
```

I have 2 issues:  First, I don't see my `links` data changing in the Vue Chrome Tools.  I am assuming I am doing something wrong with 'value'.  I was thinking of using 'v-model' but how would that work with a dynamic amount of items.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I don't see my `links` data changing"_? Changing where? Do you mean when you type a new value into the text fields?

Comment: hi Phil.  Yes, I am inspecting `links` and when I type new value into the inputs, the `links` data doesn't change in the Vue tools.  Looks as if it's not catching/reacting to the change

Answer (score 1):

Binding `:value` is only one-way, from the `data` to your HTML.

If you want two-way-binding, you can indeed use `v-model`

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    links: [{
        'title': "foo",
        'url': "http://www.com"
      },
      {
        'title': "foo1",
        'url': "http://www2.com"
      },
    ]
  })
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in links" :key="index">
    <input v-model="item.url" />
  </div>
  <pre>links = {{ links }}</pre>
</div>
```